# Desafio Problema MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Dispongo de 3 tablas y quiero rellenar una 4 tabla con estas anteriores.

Las 3 tablas son las siguientes:

**inal** --> Guarda la informacion de los dispositivos inalambricos.
**electricmeter** --> Guarda la informacion de los lectores electricos.
**dispositivos** --> Guarda la informacion sobre todos los dispositivos y en que edificio estan sitiados.

**viergy** --> La tabla vacia que se quiere rellenar con las otras 3. Guarda un titulo(datetime) de la tabla inal o electric meter (coinciden). Ademas guarda el nombre del edificio(varchar250) de la tabla dispositivos. De la tabla inal guarda el numero de conexiones(float) para ese datetime en ese edificio y de la tabla electric meter el numero de energia_activa(float)

Que procedimiento se podria seguir en MySQL para rellenar la tabla Viergy?
Crear una vista? y despues volcarla en la tabla?

[image: Imagen de las tablas].

Comment: Y el problema es? ....

Comment: Edita esto y añade donde ocupas ayuda

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto parece un ejercicio de la facultad. Si es asi, tenes que agregar que intentaste y que no funciono

Comment: ¿Cómo se relacionan las tres tablas?

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice JLPrieto, sería bueno que indiques cuáñes son las relaciones de las tablas, para poder hacer los joins. De todas formas, el proceso lo puedes hacer con un INSERT SELECT, como muestro a continuación:

```
INSERT INTO viergy (titulo, nombre_edificio, conexiones, energia)
SELECT e.titulo, d.nombre_edificio, i.conexiones, e.energia_activa 
FROM dispositivos d LEFT JOIN electrimeter e ON d.alias = e.alias 
LEFT JOIN inal i ON i.titulo = e.titulo
```

Es tan sencillo como hacer un select que te devuelva los datos como los quieres, y ponerlo en lugar de los "VALUES" en un INSERT. La query que escribí posiblemente no funcione o genere datos erróneos, pero ta dará una idea de cómo resolver el problemas sin necesidad de crear una vista.